# crond php server crash

Tags: centos, cron, php

My CentOS server crashed with 100% memory with swapping, after running fine for a week. Investigating the /var/log/messages shows me the following: https://pastebin.com/CSF8DDzX Basically, alot of the following:

```
Feb 12 23:31:32 [localhost] kernel: [31186]     0 31186    85296        0     116     1108             0 php
Feb 12 23:31:32 [localhost] kernel: [31252]     0 31252    45588        1      44      230             0 crond
Feb 12 23:31:32 [localhost] kernel: [31253]     0 31253    85296        0     112     1108             0 php
Feb 12 23:31:32 [localhost] kernel: [31315]     0 31315    45588        1      44      230             0 crond
Feb 12 23:31:32 [localhost] kernel: [31316]     0 31316    85296        0     116     1107             0 php
Feb 12 23:31:32 [localhost] kernel: [31377]     0 31377    45588        1      44      230             0 crond
```

It looks like it is stuck in a loop. My crontab -e shows me this:

```
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * php PeriodicallyKillWorkers.php
* * * * * php cheduleWorker.php
```

The scripts work fine, as does/did crontab. Where do I investigate further?

Comment: Please if you downvote my question, tell me why so I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run this every minute:

```
* * * * * php cheduleWorker.php
```

Check what is inside and how much time it take to exec this script. And add full paths to the program and script

Also check the other job (how long in run, how much memory it use and so on)

Comment: if I time this php script: real    0m0.053s
What it does is loop over a few database records and publish a rabbitmq message. I don't think the real paths will give you any additional info. What might be important is that the files are located on an network drive which disconnected for a small period of time.

Comment: @Gudgip, this (network drive) can cause the problem. Better wrap the php in shell checking if drive is mounted. Also check the other job (how long in run, how much memory it use and so on)

Comment: The other job time: real    0m0.260s. This job kills all supervisord (=rabbitmq worker) jobs every 4 hours. Wrapping in a shell is indeed a good idea. Do you have any idea why it produces so much memory?

Comment: @Gudgip, it can be some deadlock when you deal with MQ/database. Better add to the script a lot of control prints and via shell script add dedicated for each cron instance log and check.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I'll try this. :)